# SYNC SMS in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-asynctask, flutter-dependencies

I get all device SMS on my Flutter app and display it on the list on the home screen. But I could not understand how I sync my all SMS on screen every time. if any suggestions for me. What is the best way in the Flutter app to SYNC SMS on screen every time?

How to sync SMS on screen in Flutter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.